# access multiple viewControllers from the main viewControllers programmatically in a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

first part of my question is basic understanding.

I believe the other viewControllers in the storyboard are in a "Non instantiated" form when application is launched, and are launched when they are sequed, please confirm?

Second part how do I programmatically instantiate a sibling UIViewController within the storyboard and optionally create a seque to it. I've found some code from Objective-C (pasting below) but looking for a solution in SWIFT.

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first statement is true to a certain extent. Any controller connected to one that does get instantiated by a relationship segue or an embed segue will also be instantiated (like all the children of a tab bar controller). In your code snippet, you don't need to use storyboardWithName: if you're calling that method from a controller that was created in the same storyboard; you can just use self.storyboard.

```
var myVC = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController")
```

Comment: okay, got it. I hope `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` will return the existing instance if it has already been instantiated by the relationship instead of creating a new one. Please enlighten.

Comment: from the docs: **This method creates a new instance of the specified view controller each time you call it.**

Comment: @Andre based on my limited knowledge I feel any seque's that I've defined in the storyboard, a programatic transition to it will actually go to the on within the storyboard, but not to the new instance. I might end up with two instances of the same ViewController. Is there a way to get the existing instance if it exists

Comment: please tell me a little more about what you are trying to achieve... then it will be easier to help you :)

Comment: let me attempt... let's say I've two viewController with segues defined. each ViewController has a `Mediator` (GOF patterns). first of all I don't want to have two instances of the second ViewController in memory, I need to have one copy. I suspect the iOS will instantiate the second one because of the sequel relationship, and my code will instantiate one too, down the road they could be in different states (Mediator setting values on manually instantiated one)

Comment: I suspect that the one my code instantiate having it's mediator eventually will change the state (visual/text) but the one instantiated by iOS will not have those changes, and pragmatic seque will transition to the viewController (instantiated by iOS) with the default state.

Comment: my objective is to have one copy and set Mediator on it, either get hold of the existing one or instantiate manually. There should be some kind of array somewhere having references to all these ViewControllers of the storyboard, why they seem to be hidden and not accessible

Comment: @user2727195 If you only want one instance of a controller, and it's the destination view controller of a segue, then you should not instantiate one in code also. Segues, other than unwind segues, always create new view controllers, so you either need to use a segue or instantiate one on code (then push or present it), but not both.

Comment: @rdelmar yes you're right, but then the requirement is to get hold of the existing copy to be able to set Mediator on it. It's a pattern requirement. I did a `println` inside `init` for the second view controller, and it's getting called, question is how do I get reference to it from `appDelegate` or another `ViewController`. I hope my question is getting clearer

Comment: @user2727195 when the segue is executed, prepareForSegue is called on the source view controller. You can get a reference to the one you're segueing to with the property, segue.destinationViewController.

Comment: @rdelmar that will happen way down i.e. if seque is executed, i need reference to All of them at launch time (to be able to set Mediators on them). stuck :(

Comment: @user2727195, well there's no way to do that using segues. I don't know about the Mediator pattern, but it doesn't sound like it will work using a storyboard (if it's true that you need to reference them all at launch time). Why do you need to set the Mediator on them at launch time?

Comment: i do not not that pattern either... but let me ask: why do you need references to viewcontrollers that aren't on screen yet?

Comment: @rdelmar appreciate your help, I'll take this up with Apple developer support, but let's try again. Suppose I've 10 ViewControllers in a storyboard and my quick test tell me that all of them are instantiated irrespective they are on screen or not and they exist in memory. Is there a way to get hold of these objects from anywhere in the app? why are they hidden from us developers?

Comment: @AndreSlotta to be able to develop a decoupled application with ViewControllers having no knowledge of each other, All managed by their Mediators in an app (it's another discussion, please lookup GOF book). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern

Comment: in that case storyboards really do not seem to suit very well... :)

Comment: @AndreSlotta please describe the alternate approach? (I'm coming from other platform/languages)

Comment: @user2727195 You can still use the storyboard to create all your fire controllers, but don't use segues. Instantiate each one in code, and then you will have a reference to them all. I don't think this is a good approach though, to have them all instantiated at the beginning.

Comment: @rdelmar that's true. setup your viewcontrollers in storyboard without connecting them via segues. give them identifiers and instantiate them in code via `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`

Comment: @rdelmar that will work with the downside that there's another unused copy held in memory already instantiated by the system, right?

Comment: Can someone please tell me why `init` is called each time seque pushes into the view. shouldn't `init` be called only once. and I don't see `deinit` getting called.

Comment: @user2727195 Init should be called only once when the view controller is created. If you're not seeing deinit called, then you're probably doing something wrong. Are you going back to previous controller with a segue?

Comment: @rdelmar yes I've a previous seque as well, I guess that's holding on to it but then once it goes back it calls the init again.

Comment: @user2727195 As I stated above, segues, other than unwinds always create new controllers. So, if you go back to a previous controller, you should only do so using an unwind segue.